# Unchecked/unconfirmed cast

Tags: android, casting, onclicklistener

i am having unchecked/unconfirmed cast issue in my code. can it be solved without type casting or any other solution is there then please suggest. thanks.

here is my code-

```
public OnClickListener getLblSelectUnSelectMenuListener() {
        return new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView text = (TextView) v;
                if (!text.getText().equals("")) {
                    if (getPreviouslySelected().isChecked()) {
                        checkOrUnCheckSelectedItem(false);

                    } else {
                        checkOrUnCheckSelectedItem(true);
                    }
                }


            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the right way you use. Because this view component that you use expect this OnClickListener and that OnClickListener, that you use, is for other view components too.

The Interface (View.OnClickListener) doesn't know what special type of view is clicked, the interface only know, that a type thats extends the class View is clicked.